# How to access instance variable of Java in DSL?

Tags: java, eclipse, dsl, xtext, xtend

I have a *data model*(Car.java), *source template*(dsl file) and *application program*.

Template Class `Car.java`

```
public class Car {

    public String name;
    public  int price;

    public Car() {
    }
}
```

Template file `index.template`

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>  
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>        
        {FOR car : cars}
            <tr>
                <td>{car.name}</td> 
                <td>{car.price}</td>
            </tr>   
    </table>                
</body>
```

*Note:* *Plain text enriched with template notation elements which are enclosed by `{ }`*

Using the template in the program:

```
Car c1 = new Car("??", 52642);
Car c2 = new Car("??", 29000);
Car c3 = new Car("??", 9000);
List<Car> cars= new ArrayList<>();
cars.add(c1);
...
...
```

The *output* should be all the elements of the cars collection.

**Problem?**

I haven't any access to `cars` (instance variable) from the application program in a template file.
How can I get instance variable `cars` (not java class like `Car`) in `index.template` file?

Comment: Did you already have a look at xbase

Comment: I subjectively feel you're asking on what tool can you use to accomplish that DSL render of an object properties; however your question is saying how to access a variable from the template file (in simpler words, you are asking about scope). If I am correct, then that is probably the reason for the downvote. You might want to modify your question asking exactly what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look about Xbase. In the official documentation: https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/305_xbase.html

Xbase provides integration for all DSLs with the java type system.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already have access to Java types, How can I get the instance variables of java types(like cars)?

Comment: This is done by implementing the jvmmodelinferrer right